# Reposition divs in mobile

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a site made in Bootstrap with 3 columns. First is a logo, second is a menu, and third is another logo. Everything looks ok in a regular screen:
[image]

Now I want that when a user is seeing the website on mobile, it shows both logos on the first line, and the menu in the second line. How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 "><img src="<?=Url::base(true);?>/images/logo-isr.png" id="logo-isr"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 ">
        <div id="menu">
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/']) ?>">HOME</a>    <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/historia']) ?>">HISTORIA</a> <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/institucional']) ?>">INSTITUCIONAL</a> <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/rossellana']) ?>">FLIA. ROSSELLANA</a> <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/noticias']) ?>">NOTICIAS</a> <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/fotos']) ?>">FOTOS</a> <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/administracion']) ?>">ADMINISTRACIÓN</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><img src="<?=Url::base(true);?>/images/logo-congregacion.png" id="logo-congregacion"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [push/pull classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering) for this. Structure your HTML in a mobile-first fashion(IE have the 2 logos directly adjacent to each other to begin with and then when you get to the `col-md` breakpoint, push the 2nd logo over 8 columns and pull the navigation back 2 columns):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2"><img src="<?=Url::base(true);?>/images/logo-isr.png" id="logo-isr"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 col-md-push-8"><img src="<?=Url::base(true);?>/images/logo-congregacion.png" id="logo-congregacion"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-2">
        <div id="menu">
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/']) ?>">HOME</a>    <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/historia']) ?>">HISTORIA</a> <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/institucional']) ?>">INSTITUCIONAL</a> <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/rossellana']) ?>">FLIA. ROSSELLANA</a> <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/noticias']) ?>">NOTICIAS</a> <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/fotos']) ?>">FOTOS</a> <span class="font-celeste">|</span>
            <a href="<?= Url::to(['/site/administracion']) ?>">ADMINISTRACIÓN</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```